# I don't find anything wrong in this method except naming convention, do you?

Tags: c#

I was trying to find the anomolies in the below code but i couldn't find anything except bad naming convention.

```
public static Response DoIt(ADUser user)
{
    string search = "(cn=" + user.name.Trim() + ")";
    // More code lines
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for? May be you can at least say what type of interview this question come up in (test/dev/lead)?

Comment: Their is no argument check for user nor name (could both be `null`).

Comment: @oliver , you are exactly right, i was missing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not returning an `Response` type object, other than that it is fine. You may replace strings in double quotes (`"(cn="`) with constant if you are using it in more than one place. If you are worried about concatenation of string in a single line, then it is OK. But if you need to concatenate string `search` within a loop or something that requires to much concatenation then you may consider using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to build your string.

Comment: There is likely more code (... at the end). So OP probably looks for something specific to this line.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong but you can make it more readable by using [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
string search = string.Format("(cn={0})", user.name.Trim());
```